# Copy/Paste Visible Cells from Filtered sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have written this code and it has worked until now.

I have put two `AutoFilter` to pull certain rows. How do I amend the code to copy and paste visible rows?

I tried

```
Set TempRng = TempSH.Range("A1:DA" & TempSH.Range("B" & TempSH.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy'
```

which copies the cells but then I get an error. Object required

```
Sub LoopThrough()

    Dim MyFile As String, Str As String, MyDir As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet, MasterRange As Range, TempWB As Workbook, TempSH As Worksheet, TempRng As Range
    Dim NewMasterLine As Long

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    MyDir = "C:\Users\eldri\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder (2)\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xls")
    ChDir MyDir

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Do While MyFile <> ""
      'opens excel
      Set TempWB = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=MyFile, UpdateLinks:=False, 

Password:=CalcPassword(MyFile))
          Set TempSH = TempWB.Worksheets(1)
          Columns(1).Insert
          Range("c2").Copy Range("A4:A10000")
          Worksheets("Data").Range("A4").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="AMS"
          Worksheets("Data").Range("A4").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="XNE"
          Set TempRng = TempSH.Range("A1:DA" & TempSH.Range("B" & TempSH.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

      NewMasterLine = sh.Range("B" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
      If NewMasterLine > 1 Then NewMasterLine = NewMasterLine + 1
      Set MasterRange = sh.Range("A" & NewMasterLine & ":CW" & (NewMasterLine + TempRng.Rows.Count))
      MasterRange.Value = TempRng.Value
      'Debug.Print "Imported File: " & MyFile & ", Imported Range: " & TempRng.Address & ", Destination Range: " & MasterRange.Address
      TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

      MyFile = Dir()

    Loop

MsgBox ("Done")

ErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "An error occurred." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Last file that was attempted to be opened: " & MyFile & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Err.Description
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: *"I get an error"* and which? You shoud include the error message in your question. Also you didn't ask a question yet. Note that if there are no visible cells returned by `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` you cannot `.Copy` directly. First set that to your variable `Set TempRng` without using `.Copy`, then check if there are visible cells found `If TempRng Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No visible cells!":Exit Sub` and finally copy using `TempRng.Copy`.

Comment: Hey @Pᴇʜ  The above code is the code that works but it copies the rows I have filtered out as well, I have not used copy I have done it using range, just not sure how to amend the range to copy only visible cells. I am still quite new to Vba and stackoverflow, so apologies for any stupidity :). Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you try what I said in my comment? That should solve that error. Also see my more detailed answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the code with the advice from @PEH and it worked - Please find the new code below.

```
   Sub LoopThrough()

        Dim MyFile As String, Str As String, MyDir As String
        Dim sh As Worksheet, MasterRange As Range, TempWB As Workbook, TempSH As Worksheet, TempRng As Range, TempRow As Range
        Dim NewMasterLine As Long

        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

        ' Change address to suite
        MyDir = "C:\Users\eldri\OneDrive\Desktop\W220Q1\"
        MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xls")
        ChDir MyDir

        ' The following lines will put excel in a state similar to "frozen" mode. This will increase the code performance, as CPU will solely focus on performing
        ' the operations required by the code and not on showing the changes happening on excel
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        ' Here starts the loop related to the files in folder
        Do While MyFile <> ""
          'TempWB is a Worksheet object - will be the importing worksheet. TempRng is the used range in sheet 1 of the workbook
          Set TempWB = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=MyFile, UpdateLinks:=False, Password:=CalcPassword(MyFile))
          Columns(1).Insert
          Range("c2").Copy Range("A4:A10000")
          Set TempSH = TempWB.Worksheets(1)

          Set TempRng = TempSH.Range("A1:DA" & TempSH.Range("A" & TempSH.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

          'NewMasterLine is the last used row (+1) of the Master Workbook (It is basically where the new rows wiill start to be imported)
          NewMasterLine = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
          If NewMasterLine > 1 Then NewMasterLine = NewMasterLine + 1

          'This will loop through all the rows of the range to be imported, checking the first column.
          ' If the value in the second column is work-xne-ams, will import the single row in the master worklbook
          For Each TempRow In TempRng.Rows
            If TempRow.Cells(1, 3).Value = "AMS" And TempRow.Cells(1, 4).Value = "XNE" Or TempRow.Row < 4 Then
              Set MasterRange = sh.Range("A" & NewMasterLine & ":CW" & NewMasterLine)
              MasterRange.Value = TempRow.Value
              NewMasterLine = NewMasterLine + 1
            End If
          Next

          TempWB.Close savechanges:=False
          MyFile = Dir()

        Loop

    MsgBox ("Done")


    ErrorHandler:
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "An error occurred." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Last file that was attempted to be opened: " & MyFile & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Err.Description
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End Sub

    Function CalcPassword(FileName As String) As String
      CalcPassword = ""
      On Error Resume Next
      Dim TheFile As String: TheFile = Split(Split(FileName, "\")(UBound(Split(FileName, "\"))), ".")(0)
      Dim PWD As Range: Set PWD = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PWD").ListObjects("PWD").DataBodyRange
      CalcPassword = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TheFile, PWD, 5, False)
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `Set` and `.Copy` in one line.

First you need to set your range of visible cells:

```
Set TempRng = TempSH.Range("A1:DA" & TempSH.Range("B" & TempSH.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Then you need to test if there were visible cells found and if so you can copy them:

```
If Not TempRng Is Nothing Then
    TempRng.Copy
    'all code that relies on the copied range `TempRng` needs to go here
Else
    MsgBox "No visible cells found!"
End If
```

Comment: With this code I got a msgbox saying no visible cells.                                                                                                   If Not TempRng Is Nothing Then
      TempRng.Copy
      Set TempRng = TempSH.Range("A1:DA" & TempSH.Range("B" & TempSH.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

      Else
      MsgBox "No visible cells found!"
      End If